# Why are "machine-learned" entities and "descriptors" missing from LUIS?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Please see the screen below. In my LUIS authoring console, I seem to be missing the "machine-learned" entity type as well as the "descriptors" option in my left nav rail. The tutorials I am following--all recent as of this post--are showing that I need to use these options.

Have these options been deprecated or something? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the **luis.ai** portal instead of **preview.luis.ai** portal.

**Creating entities in luis.ai portal**:
[image]

**Creating entities in preview portal**:
[image]

There has been a change in how one models LUIS entities with the move from v2 to v3 LUIS API versions. LUIS is moving away from different types of entities towards instead moving to using a single ML entity to encapsulate a concept. The ML entity can have children entities to help describe or restrict what would be identified as that parent ML entity.

Changes in preview version of the LUIS portal are planned to switch over sometime post-Microsoft Build (2020) Conference.

Also it appears "descriptor" will be renamed to "feature" as well.